# How to monitor file changes on network mapped drives?

Tags: macos, networking, fsevents

From what I see, network mapped drives appear as subfolders of  the /Volumes folder.

What is the proper way to get file changes updates (delete/create/update) from this folder?

Would /dev/fsevents work for that?

How does Finder know about the changes?

Comment: Unless the file sharing protocol includes a way for the server to notify the client of changes (and I don't know of any protocols that do this), it won't be possible.

Comment: That makes sense, but still: how does Finder do it?

Comment: @Gordon - NTFS and SMB allow client notifications of changes (even mapped network drives if its a Windows system running NTFS). But the Linux machines I have interop'd with running SAMBA don't fire the event. So its kind of like only Microsoft provides the feature even though any provider should be able to offer it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson also the OS X native AFP sends notifications, just check ed with fseventer and my os x client/server setup.

Comment: @Jamie Are you looking for a way to implement this in an Cocoa-Application? Swift or ObjC?

Comment: @mahaltertin I was looking to implement this using C/C++ as standalone app and use some form of interprocess communication to send the data to another app.

Comment: @Jamie great, so have a look at my answer which points you to the documentation of two APIs which you can use in your C/C++ app.

Comment: @Jamie I'd love to win that bounty. What else would you need in my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, OS X mounts the network drives in /Volumes

The way to get file change updates is to use [File System Events API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH1-SW1). It is a C-based API where you would watch for all changes in specific directories (or even `/`).

You would create the stream with [`FSEventStreamCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSEventStreamCreate) and starting it with [`FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop)

Be prepared to dig into the header-file as there is more documentation on it as in the Reference documentation

From what I can tell, Finder probably uses some internal API or the [kernel queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html) which are more complex to setup than the higher-level API of FSEvents.h

There is a nice GUI to helping you see how the whole events come in. It's called [fseventer by fernlightning](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) (not yet Yosemite ready)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fswatch`, which I find easest to install via `homebrew`. And, yes it does use FSEvents. Then you just do:

```
fswatch /Volumes/MUSIC
```

where `MUSIC` is a Samba-based music server on my network.

Here is how it looks in action... first I show the mounted volumes (and that MUSIC is Samba based) in the top window, then I start `fswatch` in the bottom left window, then I make modifications in the filesystem in the top window and you can see them happen in the Finder and also see in the bottom left window that `fswatch` tracks all the events.

[image]

You can also use it to interact with another program whenever events are detected, like this (extracted from the `fswatch` manpage):

Probably the simplest way to pipe `fswatch` to another program in order to respond to an event is
 using xargs:

```
   $ fswatch -0 [opts] [paths] | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} [command]
```

- fswatch -0 will split records using the NUL character.
- xargs -0 will split records using the NUL character. This is required to correctly match
       impedance with fswatch.
- xargs -n 1 will invoke command every record.  If you want to do it every x records, then
       use xargs -n x.
- xargs -I {} will substitute occurrences of {} in command with the parsed argument.  If
       the command you are running does not need the event path name, just delete this option.
       If you prefer using another replacement string, substitute {} with yours.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed fswatch usage sample! I was asking this from a developer's point of view but from a user perspective your answer is a great one.

Comment: @Mark can `fswatch` work when changing files on a remote computer that has a mapped volume to macos? I have a windows network map and `fswatch` works when I change a file to that directory from inside the mac comp, but it does not display anything when I change a file using the windows machine on the physical path.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Sorry, I don't know - I generally try and avoid Windows.